# Can I increase the internal network speeds by upgrading my server?

Tags: networking, virtual-machine, hyper-v, network-adapter, speed

It has recently come to my attention that a network application is not performing as well as it should over the network – compared to speeds of other setups and environments, our speeds are far below par.

We have a Gbit Patch Panel, but there are VoIP phones connected to certain PCs, choking the connection speeds too 100 Mbit/s. This is fine, as it is to be expected. However, after some extensive testing with various 3rd party programs testing the speeds of transfer of packets over the network, even without the phones choking the connection, we are lucky to achieve 100 Mbit/sec anyway.

But, then I had the "Of course" moment when I realised that the server was in fact actually hosting two Virtual Servers – the domain controller and the Application Server (where the application in question is being hosted). This means that the Gbit connection is effectively hosting three servers – the host, and the two virtual machines, both read/write communications, which is severely impacting the intended network speeds.

For reference, the host server is using a 1 Gbit connection, and the Virtuals have 10 Gbit Virtual connections. However, as explained just prior, this means nothing. 
The hypervisor is Hyper-V. 
The server is connected to a D-Link DGS-1024D; it's rated at 1 Gb/sec.

So, after some preliminary research, I have discovered that upgrading the networking hardware for my server will increase this capacity. However, as I am more software-inclined, I really have no idea on where to start in terms of hardware.

So: what can I do to upgrade the hardware for my server, to increase the capacity for network speeds?

Let me know what other information I need to provide.

Comment: Do you mean the PC gets its connection _through_ the VoIP phone?

Comment: @grawity yes. But that's not really important, I just mentioned that for comparison

Comment: Possibly bad cable ends or cables?  Have you real world tested your cables speeds?  Can you max out your cables to over 100 MBs?  Like file transfer end to end, ssd to ssd or something?  Start at the server patch.

Comment: @Damon yes. CAT5e cables, I've tested everything, and I have identified this situation as the choke point.

Comment: The entire network's speed is slow, or just this one server-driven application, whose traffic goes through phones?

Comment: What's your hyper-visor? VMWare? Hyper-V?

Comment: Could you give us the make/model of the switch your server is connected to? This will greatly impact available upgrade options.

Comment: @Xen2050 Any read/write communication to/from the Virtual Servers (both Virtual Servers) is slow. Everything else is communicating as per normal.

Comment: @spikey_richie Hyper-V.

Comment: @floxOne It's a D-Link DGS-1024D. It's rated at 1Gb/sec

Comment: @Ben I've answered your question, but my first thought for your problem would be disk I/O. Is the host using multiple disks? SSDs? RAID config?

Comment: @floxOne I actually came to the same conclusion as you, in regards to adding another network card. But to answer your question, yes, we are using multiple disks, SATA & SAS. As for the RAID config, I *believe* it is either 0 or 1, but I can't be sure off the top of my head

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without upgrading your switch, the only solution I see would be adding a second network card to the host, and dedicate the use of this card to a specific VM (you could add a third card if the host also has significant traffic by itself).

If your VMs both have the performance to go beyond 1Gbps, I believe you would also have to upgrade your switch to one that supports bonding and/or 10 Gbps to see an improvement over the first step.

This should help if the network is the bottleneck, depending on the disk configuration of your host and the read/write pattern of your app, storage I/O seems a more likely culprit to me.